# Variable scope involving stopwatch in C#

Tags: c#, scope

I'm creating a web service in visual studio. Even though I call studentSave 1000 ms after studentRead, the stopwatch returns 0 milliseconds. I'm guessing it has something to do with scope, but I can't see what! What do I do wrong?

```
 public class Service1 : IService1
{
    Database db;
    Stopwatch sw;
    public Service1()
    {
        sw = new Stopwatch();
        db = new Database();
    }


    public string StudentRead(int id)
    {
        sw.Start();
        return db.getSentenceAtId(id);
    }

    public bool StudentSave(int id, int sentenceId, int acc, int speed)
    {
        sw.Stop();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ElapsedMilliseconds: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds); 
        return db.saveStudentResult(id, sentenceId, acc, speed);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it takes a full ms to accomplish your task?  Check `ElapsedTicks` for more precision

Comment: Can you show the code that calls StudentRead and StudentSave? Could you be calling different instances of Service1?

Comment: Are you instantiating a new `Service1` instance to save the student?

Comment: I have tried starting and stopping in the same method and then it works fine, millis is precise enough.

Answer (score 6):

The service is stateless - meaning that two calls will not hit the same instance.

If you want to measure the time between two call you can either store the time in the request/response, or save the time from one call in a persistent storage and retrieve it when the next call occurs.

See here other ways to manage state: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/86007/ways-to-do-WCF-instance-management-Per-call-Per